# How to store multiple Json object data in local storage & if existing how to update it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, cart, shopping-cart

In my angular project have a shopping cart feature. Soi wants some help from anyone.

#### 1. How to check that user previously adds to cart (by matching existing product ID in Local storage with new selected product ID), now selected product.

#### 2. If add previously to cart, how to update it(new Quantity or new Type to under existing product ID).

#### 3. If did not add previously, how to push to local storage as a new product under new Product ID. Can't to be effect other selected cart product

Angular 7 cli

### Product.components.ts

```
constructor(private cartService:CartServicesService)

public addToCart(productId : any , productTypeStatus:any , quantityCount:any ){ 

var cartProductData = { 
  "productId": productId,
  "productSelectedTypeId": productTypeStatus,
  "productQuantity": quantityCount
};  

this.cartService.addToCart(cartProductData); //send data to cart-service.ts

}
```

### Cart-services.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartServicesService {

constructor() { }

public addToCart(cartData:any) {

 console.log(cartData);

 //save data in local storage------------------------------------
 localStorage.setItem('cartObject', JSON.stringify(cartData)); 

 }
}
```

### In local storage

```
Key   : cartObject
Value : {"productId":3,"productSelectedTypeId":null,"productQuantity":4}
```

Comment: There can be more than one item within the `cartObject` in localStorage, right?

Comment: Yes. can have more than one as `{"productId":3,"productSelectedTypeId":null,"productQuantity":4}` like this object.

Comment: In that case, they should be stored as an array? Rather than an object?

Comment: hummm. I think so.

Comment: Can you help me to that, because little bit confuses with verifying part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the steps you have mentioned on your question, are generally correct. However, I would recommend you to store it as an array of objects, instead of just an object on its own.

This is how you can get the cart data from your localStorage.

```
let cart =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartObject'));
```

Then, we use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the new item on your shopping list exists on the cart from `cartObject`.

```
let isInCart = false;
if (cart) {
  isInCart = cart.some(item => item.productId === 
cartProductData.productId));
} else {
  cart = [];
}
```

Then, we handle it based on `isInCart`, which is a boolean value that denotes if the item exists on the cart:

```
if (isInCart) {
  cart.map(item => {
    if (item.productId === cartProductData.productId) {
      item.productQuantity += cartProductData.productQuantity;
    }
    return item;
  });
} else {
  cart.push(cartProductData);
}
```

Then, we store the updated `cart` on your localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('cartObject', JSON.stringify(cart));
```

Comment: it's will get error friend... `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of null`

Comment: Did you carry out the first step? `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartObject'));`? If yes, what did you get when you `console.log(cart)`?

Comment: yup. I put it. I think in an initial moment did not have `cartObject` in local storage.

Comment: Ok, I have made some changes to my code to do some null checks. Please refer to the changes on the first 2 blocks of code.

Comment: `cart--> null` form  `console.log("cart--> "+ cart);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192750/discussion-between-wentjun-and-thevin-malaka).

Answer (score 1):

localStorage stores the values in a key, value pair.

1) Make the key unique to user and store their products.

2) If there are multiple products store as an array of cart object for the user key as value.

3) If you want to update a single product in list of values, retrieve the list from storage modify the required value in it, replace the list in the storage. (Since its map, adding another pair with same key will replace/overwrite the existing values for that key).

4) If you want to update the whole list, just replace the values for the user key.